# Why does Python's socket.getfqdn() return a long string that looks like an IPv6 host rather than what `hostname -f` returns?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, backup

Why does Python's `socket.getfqdn()` return `'1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa'` rather than matt-mmf-macbook.local?

```
mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$ python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa'
>>> 

mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$ hostname
matt-mmf-macbook.local

mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$ hostname -f
matt-mmf-macbook.local
```

The unexpected output of `socket.getfqdn()` is making my Duplicity backups fail with the output below. My last successful Duplicity backup was on 12/19.

```
mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$ ~/config/bash/backup.sh
Reading globbing filelist /Users/mlm/config/bash/backup-include-matt-mmf-macbook.txt
Reading globbing filelist /Users/mlm/config/bash/backup-exclude-matt-mmf-macbook.txt
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Warning, found the following remote orphaned signature files:
duplicity-new-signatures.20110929T140604Z.to.20110929T143209Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20110929T143209Z.to.20110929T150055Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20110929T150055Z.to.20110929T161503Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20110929T161503Z.to.20110930T161505Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20110930T161505Z.to.20111005T024235Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111005T024235Z.to.20111005T024907Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111005T024907Z.to.20111005T161508Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111005T161508Z.to.20111006T161509Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111006T161509Z.to.20111007T161507Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111007T161507Z.to.20111010T161511Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111010T161511Z.to.20111011T161507Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111011T161507Z.to.20111012T161510Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111012T161510Z.to.20111013T161505Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111013T161505Z.to.20111017T161506Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111017T161506Z.to.20111018T161505Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111018T161505Z.to.20111019T161506Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111019T161506Z.to.20111020T161506Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111020T161506Z.to.20111021T161511Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111021T161511Z.to.20111025T161507Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111025T161507Z.to.20111026T161510Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111026T161510Z.to.20111027T161506Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111027T161506Z.to.20111028T161511Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111028T161511Z.to.20111104T161506Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20111104T161506Z.to.20111115T222417Z.sigtar.gpg
Last full backup date: Wed Nov 16 12:16:14 2011
Fatal Error: Backup source host has changed.
Current hostname: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa
Previous hostname: matt-mmf-macbook.local

Aborting because you may have accidentally tried to backup two different data sets to the same remote location, or using the same archive directory.  If this is not a mistake, use the --allow-source-mismatch switch to avoid seeing this message

mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$
```

My backup.sh contains:

```
#! /bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:$PATH

. ~/config/bash/awskeys.sh

. $(type -p virtualenvwrapper.sh)
workon duplicity

ulimit -n 1024

duplicity \
    --encrypt-key DEADBEEF \
    --include-globbing-filelist ~/config/bash/backup-include-$(hostname -s).txt \
    --exclude-globbing-filelist ~/config/bash/backup-exclude-$(hostname -s).txt \
    / \
    s3://s3.amazonaws.com/backup-$(hostname -s)/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I navigated to System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > TCP/IP, and changed Configure IPv6 from:

```
Off
```

to:

```
Automatically
```

And now I get what I expect:

```
mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$ python -c 'import socket ; print socket.getfqdn()'
matt-mmf-macbook.local

mlm@matt-mmf-macbook.local:~
$
```

I also notice that Off is no longer an option after changing to Automatically.

Comment: So instead of fixing your code you turn off IPv6? I'm not sure that this is a future-proof solution :-) In fact, it means I cannot ever run your software.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. IPv6 _was_ `Off`; I don't know wny or how it got that way. I changed IPv6 to `Automatically`, which fixed the issue in my original question.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem. getfqfn() was returning 'local.localdomain' instead of the value 'host.mydomain.com' returned by `hostname`. Checking the [getfqfn() docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn) shows:

> Return a fully qualified domain name for name. If name is omitted or
>   empty, it is interpreted as the local host. **To find the fully
>   qualified name, the hostname returned by gethostbyaddr() is checked**,
>   followed by aliases for the host, if available. The first name which
>   includes a period is selected. In case no fully qualified domain name
>   is available, the hostname as returned by gethostname() is returned.

In my case, getfqdn() was actually looking in my /etc/hosts, which listed:

```
127.0.0.1 local.localdomain localhost host.mydomain.com
```

Since the "real" hostname was at the end, and "local.localdomain" is "the first name which includes a period", that's the one it used. Changing my /etc/hosts to:

```
127.0.0.1 host.mydomain.com local.localdomain localhost
```

caused the correct hostname to be returned.

I think a similar issue is occurring for you.

Comment: thanks, python is really stupid about it - it should just tell what 'hostname -f' tells and not think too much

Comment: Instead of changing the first line of the hosts file as suggested, you should add a line after the first 2 "standard" entries that contains "ipAddress host.mydomain.com host".  This should also fix the issue without altering the localhost settings which in general should not be altered.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that it simply skips the local DNS resolution and goes straight to asking the internet for the hostname.

The only correct hostname for the IPv6 address `::1` is `1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa`, plus the name defined locally - but the internet doesn't know that one.

Comment: It does seem that it's resolving ::1 rather than 127.0.0.1. Any idea why that might have changed on my MacBook Pro between 12/19 and 12/23?

Comment: OS X uses algorithms to choose between IPv4 and IPv6. Applications are supposed to support both v4 and v6, or simply fall back to v4 when v6 isn't supported by the app. The "why did OS X do this?" shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your help. I found the problem and added an answer to this question.